# Oracle Apex Link column to another report

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex

i am trying to link column in interactive report in Oracle Apex and trying to show another report behalf of this report.
For example if run a report of yearly sales of company and i make year column as link and on click of that column i want to show the monthly report of that year. please help me about how to make column as link and how to get that link column on target report

Comment: Hi, which Apex version you are using?

Comment: i am using Apex 5.1.1

Comment: you got the solution or still searching. What is your progress?